# Exception while adding controller in MVC3 - file of assembly could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I'm experiencing this weird problem which is driving me nuts. I have a MVC3 project in Visual Studio 2010 which used to work normally. For some strange reason, when I try to add a controller I get an exception. (see screenshot). When I try to add a view, the dialog just closes without notice.

I have added the Griffin.MvcContrib as a NuGet package - which was working properly. I have never used the assembly as mentioned in the exception screen (version 1.1.2.0) - but the latest version, 1.1.2.1

I've performed a full text search within my solution - 1.1.2.0 is not found.

I've emptied caches, reinstalled the Visual Studio project templates, removed the references to Griffin.MvcContrib (uninstall via NuGet), deleted the Bin folder, rebooted my machine, nothing has helped so far. :(

The references in my project file:

```
<Reference Include="Griffin.MvcContrib, Version=1.1.2.1, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\griffin.mvccontrib.1.1.2.1\lib\net40\Griffin.MvcContrib.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Griffin.MvcContrib.Admin, Version=1.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\Griffin.MvcContrib.Admin.1.0.10\lib\net40\Griffin.MvcContrib.Admin.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Griffin.MvcContrib.SqlServer, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\Griffin.MvcContrib.SqlServer.1.0.8\lib\net40\Griffin.MvcContrib.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Anybody got any clues on how to fix my IDE/ Project?

Update: steps to reproduce:

```
Install-Package Griffin.mvccontrib -Version 1.1.2
Install-Package Griffin.MvcContrib.SqlServer
```

-- everything ok

```
Install-Package Griffin.MvcContrib.Admin
```

--> Forces an update of Griffin.mvccontrib to 1.1.2.1

--> Causes the exception as seen in the attached screenshot

Somehow installing the admin module forces an update of mvccontrib.

[image]

Comment: @jgauffin, could you please have a look at this?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've no idea why it happens. I've experienced it too. Would be great if someone could shed a light on this. I think that the different packages (Admin/SqlServer) have been compiled against different versions of MvcContrib. But there should be no breaking changes = everything should work either way. Can I compile the libraries or package the nuget packages differently to resolve this?

Comment: That seems most likely. Has Admin been compiled against mvccontrib 1.1.2.1 or made dependent on this version in the NuGet package? I have updated my question.

Comment: The question is rather why the SqlServer package forces Visual Studio to try to use 1.1.2 instead of 1.1.2.1?. Anyway I've sent an nuget update for admin so it doesn't force 1.1.2.1

Comment: Do you have any assembly bindings in web.config?

Comment: You are right, my bad. I will try out the new package. Thanks a million!

Regarding bindings: just the normal MVC binding: <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />

Answer (score 0):

I know you've searched, but check again, looking in your packages file and your web.config - look for a reference to Griffin.MvcContrib 1.1.2.0

In my experience, assemblies failing to load with that error very often means a version conflict.

If this fails, you might try looking at your project definition in notepad.

Also, check you don't have conflicting versions installed. Sometimes you may have one version in the GAC and be referencing the bare .dll of another, and this can result in a conflict.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Checking my packages.config and web.config files was the first thing I did - no references found..

Comment: I added a couple more thoughts. It has to be a version conflict, but they can be really hard to track down. Another thought: sometimes a referenced assembly or another project in the solution has a reference to a conflicting version of the dll, and this can cause the same error.

Comment: I haven't added this assembly to my GAC. Doublechecked this, it's not there. The actual reference seems irrelevant - I just need to find a way to "hard reset" my project.

Comment: I'd close VS and open the project with notepad then - delete any references by hand if they are actually in there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from a dll that's in your references which has been built against Griffin.MvcContrib 1.1.2.0. So it's going to be difficult to find.

If you can get away with it you can try removing the reference to Griffin.MvcContrib (if you don't need it) or change your packages.config file to refer to the 1.1.2.0 version of MvcContrib instead of 1.1.2.1.

Then go through all of your .csproj files and correct the references to the 1.1.2.0 path instead of the 1.1.2.1 path.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary workaround is to close the solution and just open the project to which you are trying to add the controller. It doesn't fix the conflicting references issue, but it lets you keep going with whatever you're trying to do.